# Invoice PDF or bill PDF with json and jsPDF

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create a bill in node express with Thermal printer.

I tried with this working code, and my friend said by using escape characters, alignment is not in correct position. So, how can I create it as like a restaurant invoice or billing?

**What I tried**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res)
{
    global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
    global.navigator = {};
    global.btoa = () => {};

    var fs = require('fs');
    var jsPDF = require('jspdf');

    var doc = new jsPDF();

    var sampleText = 'NO \t ITEM \t QTY \t PRICE \t AMOUNT \n \n 1 \t Sugar \t 90.00 \t 2.00 \t 180.00 \n \n 2 \t Rice  \t 80.00 \t 5.50 \t 440.00 \n \n 3 \t Biscuit \t 50.75 \t 7.00 \t 355.25 \n \n

    var data = doc.output(sampleText);

    fs.writeFileSync('./document.pdf', data);

    doc.text("Hello World", 10, 10);
    var data = doc.output();

    fs.writeFileSync('./invoice.pdf', data);

    delete global.window;
    delete global.navigator;
    delete global.btoa;
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started');

module.exports = app;
```

**Bill style**

- Should take paper size for thermal printer (i.e: 80 mm width).
- Header part should be centered (Shop name, address, Telephone and Date/Time, Counter, Bill No).
- A Horizontal seperater with dashed line.
- Buying items should be looped upto total buying items.
- PRICE and AMOUNT should be right aligned(all monetary values).
- The word Net Total, CASH and Balance should be left aligned and those values should be right aligned
- Finally Footer should be centered.

**Bill format**

```
|               Shop Name               |
|                Address                |
|               Telephone               |
|                                       |
| 13/11/2018 14:18:49  IamCoder  No: 99 |
|---------------------------------------|
| NO |   ITEM  |  PRICE | QTY |  AMOUNT |
|:--:|:-------:|:------:|:---:|--------:|
| 1  | Sugar   |  90.00 | 2.00|  180.00 |
| 2  | Rice    |  80.00 | 5.50|  440.00 |
| 3  | Biscuit |  50.75 | 7.00|  355.25 |
|---------------------------------------|
| Net Total                      975.25 |
|                                       |
| CASH                          1000.00 |
| Balance                         24.75 |
|------------IMPORTANTNOTICE------------|
| In case of a price discrepancy return |
|   the bill and item within 2 day to   |
|         refund the difference         |
```

**Sample json**

```
{
    "header": {
        "bill": "99",
        "shop": "Shop Name",
        "address": "Address",
        "telephone": "Telephone",
        "date": "13/11/2018 12:45:52",
        "counter": "IamCoder"
    },
    "items": [{
        "item": "Sugar",
        "price": "90.00",
        "qty":"2.00",
        "amount":"180.00"
    },
    {
        "item": "Rice",
        "price": "80.00",
        "qty":"5.50",
        "amount":"440.00"
    },
    {
        "item": "Biscuit",
        "price": "50.75",
        "qty":"7.00",
        "amount":"355.25"
    }],
    "footer": {
        "total":"975.25",
        "cash":"1000.00",
        "balance":"24.75",
        "notice": "In case of a price discrepancy, return the bill and item within 2 days to refund the difference."
    },
}
```

Comment: If you can convert json to html somehow
then go to this link [https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-convert-an-HTML-to-a-PDF-using-Node-js-I-need-to-take-HTML-data-not-file-or-url-but-actual-HTML-code-and-create-a-PDF-file-out-of-it-Does-anyone-have-an-experience-with-an-NPM-that-does-so-successfully]

Comment: But how can I loop the item?

Answer (score 1):

It seems jspdf generates pdf on the client side. I have used [pdfkit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfkit) on the server side with express before.

Something like:

```
const PDFDoc = require('pdfkit')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const doc = new PDFDoc()
  doc.text('hello world')
  doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'))

  res.status(200).send('OK')
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`app is running on port ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Creating pdf on client side or server side is ok. But how can I get it like a  bill.

Comment: use a combination of [`jspdf.text()`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#text) for text and drawing tables with [`jspdf.rect()`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#rect) for table ?

Comment: Is it responsible for Thermal printer width (75 mm)?

Comment: well, you can define pdf page width with [`new jspdf('p', 'mm', [75, 75])`](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html). What I am interested is, after you create the pdf, could you actually open it?

Comment: Nope! I also waited to tell that, but forgot. Pdf created but not opened(crashed).

Comment: And the page width is ok with 75mm, but height may be vary for different customers.

Comment: hmm, I very much doubt you can use `jspdf` in a node application, unless you do something hacky with `puppeteer` or `selenium`. It requires the `window.createElementNS` method to work, it seems. I would encourage you to investigate using a different library. on varying height: I don't know if it is possible to have dynamic height. AFAIK, you will need to estimate the height, by how many lines you have. Most pdf packages seems to need you to define the height on page init.

Comment: ohh! I am very confusing as a starter.

Comment: Maybe do one thing at a time? use `express` & a pdf library and save a pdf with hello world, and it can be opened fine first, then consider printing the bill in the format you want to?

Comment: Now corrected the Hello world pdf created successfully. But I do not know how to create a bill and alignment.

Comment: the hello world is left aligned, i assume?

Comment: Yeah! it is left aligned.

Comment: how do we make it center aligned?

Comment: `doc.text('Hello World', 10, 20, 'center');` ?

Comment: does it work? if not, try `doc.text('Hello World', 10, 20, {align:'center'});`

Comment: It works, but I want to circulate the items. And find the height of the printer.

Comment: that you will have to do some trial and error imo. ie, when item no. == 0, how tall it is, when item no. == 1, how tall it is, then do some arithmetic

Comment: Sorry, unable to understand.

Comment: `const restHeight = 200; const lineHeight = 15; const height = sample.items.length * lineHeight + restHeight;` - what I am saying is, you might need to guess a little, if you have dynamic height

Comment: Nice, Could you please make all of as a bundle?

Comment: can you please?

Comment: chances are no, it will take a lot of trial and error, which would probably better if you do it youself, since you have the printer

Comment: Nice, if you start with code(error or not), then I will correct with the printer.