# jsPDF, fromHTML plugin does not create PDF and says undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

The following HTML and JavaScript is used to create a receipt PDF. The PDF will print in receipt printer, the paper size in 80 mm width. And the printing height will calculate by the length of three parts(header, footer and buying items).

I tried with this code but it did not create PDF to print.

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".btn").click(function()
    {
        var contentHeight; // header + footer + number of buying items
        var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", [80, contentHeight]),
            source = $("#template_invoice"),
            margins = {
                top: 10,
                //bottom: 60,
                left: 5,
                width: 80    // Receipt printer width
            };
        doc.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top,
            {
                // y coord
                width: margins.width // max width of content on PDF
            },
            function(dispose)
            {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
                // this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                doc.save("Test.pdf");
            },
            margins
        );
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Receipt PDF</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <style>
         table{
         font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
         }
         td#aliCenter{
         text-align:center;
         }
         td#aliRight{
         text-align:right;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container" id="template_invoice">
         <table>
            <!-- header -->
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">ABC Restaurant<br>Sunny Road, Island<br>Contact : 123456789</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">15/11/2018 02:14:52&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IamCoder&nbsp;&nbsp;No: 150</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5">
                  <hr>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td id="aliCenter">NO</td>
               <td id="aliCenter">ITEM</td>
               <td id="aliCenter">QTY</td>
               <td id="aliCenter">PRICE</td>
               <td id="aliCenter">AMOUNT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5">
                  <hr>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- buying items -->
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td colspan="4">The big tasty Pizza</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>PZ4545</td>
               <td>2.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">150.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">300.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>2</td>
               <td colspan="4">Crunchy huge Buggers</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>BR7878</td>
               <td>5.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">500.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">2500.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>3</td>
               <td colspan="4">1.5 l Coca-Cola pack</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td>CC6523</td>
               <td>3.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">180.00</td>
               <td id="aliRight">540.00</td>
            </tr>
            <!-- footer -->
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5">
                  <hr>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td colspan="3">Net Total</td>
               <td id="aliRight">3340.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td colspan="3">Cash</td>
               <td id="aliRight">3500.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td colspan="3">Balance</td>
               <td id="aliRight">160.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">-----------IMPORTANT NOTICE-----------</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="5" id="aliCenter">In case of a price discrepancy, <br>return the bill and item within <br> 2 days to refund the difference</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <button class="btn btn-info pull-right">Download</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js'></script>
      <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your source is an array use source[0]

Comment: where should I use?

Comment: `source = $("#template_invoice")[0],` is this correct? But does not work

Comment: you have another error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516

Comment: @JibinMathews, So how can I use?

Answer (score 1):

You get an errror:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

because the [colspans and rowspans are not supported](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/516). And the styling is not supported too.

I wrote for you the solution with jsPDF plugin [jspdf-autotable](/questions/tagged/jspdf-autotable).

**Workaround / solution**

```js
function alignCol(cell, data, colCount)
{
    cell.styles.fillColor = false;

    var col = data.column.index;
    if(colCount == 1)
        cell.styles.halign = 'center';
    else
    {
        if(colCount == 2)
            cell.styles.halign = 'left';
        else
        {
           if(col < colCount - 1)
                cell.styles.halign = 'left';
            else cell.styles.halign = 'right'
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".btn").click(function()
    {
        var options =
            {
                margin: 0,
                colCount: 1,
                tableWidth: 226.772,
                drawHeaderRow: function(){return false},
                drawHeaderCell: function(){return false},
                createdCell: function(cell, data){alignCol(cell, data, options.colCount)}
            },
            tableWidths5 =
            {
                0: {columnWidth: 26},
                1: {columnWidth: 50},
                2: {columnWidth: 45},
                3: {columnWidth: 45},
                4: {columnWidth: 60}
            };

        // Only pt supported (not mm or in)
        var contentHeight = 400; // header + footer + number of buying items
        //80 mm = 226.772 pt
        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [contentHeight, 226.772]);
        doc.setFontSize(3);
        doc.setFont('Courier New');
        doc.autoTable([0], [['ABC Restaurant\nSunny Road, Island\nContact : 123456789\n15/11/2018   02:14:52   IamCoder   No: 150']], options);

        doc.line(0, 60, 226, 60);
        options.columnStyles = tableWidths5;
        options.startY = 60;
        options.colCount = 5;
        doc.autoTable([0,0,0,0,0], [['NO','ITEM','QTY','PRICE','AMOUNT']], options);

        doc.line(0, 80, 226, 80);
        options.columnStyles = {0: {columnWidth: 26}};
        options.startY = 80;
        options.colCount = 2;
        doc.autoTable([0,0], [[1,'The big tasty Pizza']], options);

        options.columnStyles = tableWidths5;
        options.startY = 100;
        options.colCount = 5;
        doc.autoTable([0,0,0,0,0], [[' ','PZ4545','2.00','150.00','300.00']], options);

        options.columnStyles = {0: {columnWidth: 26}};
        options.startY = 120;
        options.colCount = 2;
        doc.autoTable([0,0], [[2,'Crunchy huge Buggers']], options);

        options.columnStyles = tableWidths5;
        options.startY = 140;
        options.colCount = 5;
        doc.autoTable([0,0,0,0,0], [[' ','BR7878','5.00','500.00','2500.00']], options);

        options.columnStyles = {0: {columnWidth: 26}};
        options.startY = 160;
        options.colCount = 2;
        doc.autoTable([0,0], [[3,'1.5 l Coca-Cola pack']], options);

        options.columnStyles = tableWidths5;
        options.startY = 180;
        options.colCount = 5;
        doc.autoTable([0,0,0,0,0], [[' ','CC6523','3.00','180.00','540.00']], options);

        doc.line(0, 210, 226, 210);
        options.columnStyles = {0: {columnWidth: 26}};
        options.startY = 220;
        options.colCount = 3;
        doc.autoTable([0,0,0], [
            ['','Net Total','3340.00'],
            ['','Cash','3500.00'],
            ['','Balance','160.00']
        ], options);

        options.columnStyles = void 0;

        options.startY = 295;
        options.colCount = 1;
        doc.autoTable([0], [['----------- IMPORTANT NOTICE -----------\n\nIn case of a price discrepancy, return\nthe bill and item within 2 days\nto refund the difference.']], options);
        
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<center><button class="btn btn-info">Download PDF</button></center>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/2.3.5/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Bharata. But is that width is 80 cm? Because the thermal paper width is 80 cm

Comment: @IamCoder, you have to convert 80 mm (not cm!!!) to pt, because jsPDF-autoTable plugin supports only pt sizes. You could convert it **[here](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=convert+mm+to+pt)**, when you need it. The PDF in my example is 80mm width. Thanking on StackOverflow is done by upvoting and by answer accepting. If you are satisfied with my answer above, please mark it as accepted on the left side from my answer and upvote it.

Comment: Thank you. I told that 80 mm because of the paper size. Is it possible to change the items (The big tasty Pizza, Crunchy huge Buggers...) and those related data (`QTY, AMOUNT, CODE, PRICE, NET TOTAL , CASH`) by using them using an JSON array to used in front-end ? Otherwise, it seems to be hard coded.

Comment: @IamCoder, nothing is hard coded. All sizes you can change in front-end using JS. The PDF in my example is 80mm width. Yes, it is possible to change ALL items in JS.

Comment: Ok but your code contains all there code Which ONE place should I give the json ? like  `var data = ["items": [{ "no": "1", "code":"PZ4545", "item": "The big tasty Pizza", "price": "500.00", "qty":"2.00", "amount":"1000.00"}, {"no": "2", "code":"BR7878", "item": "Crunchy huge Buggers", "price": "250.00", "qty":"2.00", "amount":"500.00"}, { "no": "3", "code":"CC6523", "item": "1.5 l Coca-Cola pack", "price": "180.00", "qty":"3.00", "amount":"540.00" }]]`

Comment: @IamCoder, this data has nothing to do with your question! This site is not a free code writing service. I have answered your question FULLY. I have invested in your question a lot of my time. In one question you can ask/write only ONE TASK - see the site rules. This is second question.You have to create a new question, if you can not write it by yourself.

Comment: I had already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277786/invoice-pdf-or-bill-pdf-with-json-and-jspdf). If you can, please try it, please

Comment: @IamCoder, I have answered this your question correctly and I did not get any points for my work from you – my answer was not accepted and not upvoted from you. Why I have to write one answer more for you for nothing?!

Comment: Nice, good works here. But using a json/ array data is worthiness. Otherwise hard code is very difficult.

Comment: Any ideas to use json array?

Comment: @IamCoder, yes, you can write a loop for JSON. And read again [this my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53316709#comment93710580_53365742).